# Starting Spring Boot Application based on maven in "test scope"

Tags: spring-boot, maven, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks

i have written a Spring Boot Application which should use H2 during development and mariadb for integration tests and production. For developing i use Visual Studio Code in WSL2 with Java Extensions.

In pom.xml i defined H2 repository as dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.200</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

In VSCode i created the 3 launch configurations "Debug", "Debug (test)" and "Debug (prod)". In the launch.json file i defined 3 different spring profiles for the different database configurations. Here is an example for the "test" configuration:

```
{
    "type": "java",
    "name": "Debug (test)",
    "request": "launch",
    "mainClass": "de.frickeldave.fleckerlteppich.telemetry.TelemetryApplication",
    "preLaunchTask": "startmariadb",
    "postDebugTask": "stopmariadb",
    "args": "--spring.profiles.active=test"
}
```

The problem:
When i start my normal "Debug" Configuration in VSCode, i want to use the H2 database. But because of the definition `<scope>test</test>` the dependency is not loaded and the application fails to connect. It works perfectly, when i remove the "test-scope" declaration (which is not the goal).
What can i do do start the Application in test scope, to have H2 available when debugging with VSCode? Is there a start-parameter i can add?

Thanks in advance

Regards Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependencies of scope `test` are not available at runtime.

They can only be used for tests that run during the build.

Comment: Yes of course, that i have understood. I think the problem is in running it from VSCode. When starting a debug session in VSCode, it will start the session with "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=localhost:37173 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 @/tmp/cp_4qesk4copx6brwxbvmpbz94yu.argfile de.frickeldave.fleckerlteppich.telemetry.TelemetryApplication".

In this case, H2 is not loaded when scope is test. So my question was: What can i do to activate the "test" scope when running the application out of visual studio code?

Comment: Sorry, you say you have understood that you cannot use `test` scoped dependencies at runtime, but then you ask, how you can activate them when running the application? I think I cannot follow you.

Comment: Okay, i see i didn't explained not good enough. My problem is, i want to debug the application from "Visual Studio Code" with the Java Extensions. VSCode is starting the session by clicking on "Debug" with the parameters shown before and is doing "some magic" to analyze the pom.xml (i think so, because it is working when i remove the test-scope). 
My expecation is, when VSCOde is executing the application (because i am clicking on Debug) the test-scope must be enables, right? 
Or do i get it wrong (i am new to java, so sorry for asking silly questions)?

Comment: You are probably wrong. I am not a VS Code expert, but I doubt that using Debug mode will add test dependencies. Test dependencies are meant to be used in tests during the build, not when you run an application (in Debug mode or anything else). If you really need a special version of your application with more dependencies to test it at runtime, you probably need to add a profile that you activate during the build.

Comment: Thank you. I already thought that i have to use profiles in that case. Do you know if Eclipe or Intellij is managing that on another way? Are there dependencies available during a debug session when defining them in test scope?

Comment: I doubt this. This is not how test dependencies are meant to be used. Except, of course, if you debug a JUnit test.